# Which is fastest - Pure Component, Functional Component, Class Component? [React.js]

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am pretty novice in React and trying to learn up. In a recent interview the interviewer asked me the following question:

Which type of component is fastest - `pure, functional or class`.

I know that "functional component seems a bit faster than class-based" but thats all I know. I also don't know why - just people say that.

Can someone let me know the `order of fastness` of following 4 components:

1. Pure Functional
2. Functional Component
3. Pure Class-based
4. Pure Class Component

Along, with reasoning, which one is fastest, which is slowest & why?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is like asking what's the fastest function in JavaScript. With all due respect to the interviewer, it's a very "boring" question. I didn't downvote though.

Comment: @SamR. - Thanks bro! It might be boring, but what if - my selection depends on answer - & I need the job desperately! :-/

Comment: if this is the question they asked, you better not work there. Run my friend, run.

Comment: Your answers seem solid.  Their speed is going to depend on the version of React, the Browser implementation of JS, and potentially how they were transpiled (with babel).

Comment: "Fastest" is subjective also, do you mean render time? compile time? Do you mean how long it takes each to write as a developer? On boarding time for JR developer? Time to write tests for? Might help to be a little more specific on questions like these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel like this is a terrible interview question. There's no real answer to this, it's mostly just objective.

Here's what [Dan Abromov said in his blog](https://overreacted.io/how-are-function-components-different-from-classes/) back when stateful functional components started existing:

> Maybe you’ve heard one of them is better for performance. Which one?
> Many of such benchmarks are [flawed](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/this-benchmark-is-indeed-flawed-c3d6b5b6f97f?source=your_stories_page---------------------------) so I’d be careful drawing
> conclusions from them. Performance primarily depends on what the code
> is doing rather than whether you chose a function or a class. In our
> observation, the performance differences are negligible, though
> optimization strategies are a bit [different](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#are-hooks-slow-because-of-creating-functions-in-render).

Pure components can seem faster than non-pure mostly because of the optimization of not re-rendering, but if you go too far into that, you can go backwards in performance due to the many checks for equality.

That being said, the absolute fastest in react is a function. i.e. calling a function that returns jsx. Obviously you can't use state in it. The reason this is the fastest is because it avoids a lot of the internal react code because it isn't a separate component. [Source](http://Maybe%20you%E2%80%99ve%20heard%20one%20of%20them%20is%20better%20for%20performance.%20Which%20one?%20Many%20of%20such%20benchmarks%20are%20flawed%20so%20I%E2%80%99d%20be%20careful%20drawing%20conclusions%20from%20them.%20Performance%20primarily%20depends%20on%20what%20the%20code%20is%20doing%20rather%20than%20whether%20you%20chose%20a%20function%20or%20a%20class.%20In%20our%20observation,%20the%20performance%20differences%20are%20negligible,%20though%20optimization%20strategies%20are%20a%20bit%20different.)

I.e.

```
function renderDivs(){
  return <div><div></div></div>
}

/// in a component:

return <div>{renderDivs()}</div>
```

Comment: I'd argue that a function that returns `null` is faster. Or better a function that doesn't run at all is the fastest of all. Now prove me wrong.

Comment: Lol, That's fair, but that doesn't render anything. I agree for the most part it's a bit of a moot point. I think the fastest at all is to just not have an application! They can't complain about performance then!

Comment: "Not having an application" has been my fastest indeed.